# Complex Numbers: Convert to rectangular form

Tags: complex-numbers

How do I convert this to rectangular form? I know Euler's formula is how we are going to convert the complex number to a rectangular coordinate. Where i'm confused   is r being 1.6. Any help would be great!

[image]

Comment: What value of $r$ would make you less confused? Why?

Comment: I';m comparing it to the numbers that can be associated with the 30-60-90 triangle from pi/6. I dont fully understand complex numbers yet.

Comment: What does $a\angle b$ mean?

Comment: You can associate any numbers you want with the 30-60-90 triangle as long as they're in the right proportions to each other. What particular numbers did you have in mind?

Answer (score 2):

$$z=1.6\angle\frac\pi6=1.6\left(\cos\frac\pi6+i\sin\frac\pi6\right)=\frac45\sqrt{3}+\frac45i.$$

Comment: That's what you get from doing math right after taking a nap. Fixed, thanks!